# How to access the gson SerializedName annotaion value from properties file

Tags: java, spring, gson

I am trying to de-serialize my json string to my custom class ,I want to make the
@SerializedName annotation value to accessed as configurable parameter which should read values from application properties file .I have provided the below code snippet ,But it is accepting a constant string, is there any alternative way to make these parameter's as configurable

```
    {
  FName: "Sample",
  LName: "LName"}

 class Test{
     
@SerializedName(value=${"${name}"})
    private string name;
@SerializedName(value=${"${data}"})
    private string data;
}

application.properties file
name=FName
data=LName
```

Comment: Gson doesn't support placeholders, so you cannot do that.

Comment: Why don't you use @Value from Spring?

Comment: I tried with @Value but even that did not work

Answer (score 0):

Gson is not aware of any other library unless you tell it to do so (why pay for what you might never use otherwise?). You can extend Gson on top of what Gson provides using a custom implementation of the [`FieldNamingStrategy`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/FieldNamingStrategy.html) interface:

```java
public final class ValueFieldNamingStrategy
        implements FieldNamingStrategy {

    private final Environment environment;

    private ValueFieldNamingStrategy(final Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    public static FieldNamingStrategy of(final Environment environment) {
        return new ValueFieldNamingStrategy(environment);
    }

    @Override
    public String translateName(final Field f) {
        @Nullable
        final Value valueAnnotation = f.getAnnotation(Value.class);
        if ( valueAnnotation == null ) {
            return f.getName();
        }
        return environment.resolvePlaceholders(valueAnnotation.value());
    }

}
```

```java
public final class ValueFieldNamingStrategyTest {

    @org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
    public void test()
            throws IOException {
        final ConfigurableEnvironment configurableEnvironment = new StandardEnvironment();
        final MutablePropertySources propertySources = configurableEnvironment.getPropertySources();
        final PropertySource<?> propertySource = new MapPropertySource("test", ImmutableMap.of(
                "name", "FName",
                "data", "LName"
        ));
        propertySources.addLast(propertySource);
        final FieldNamingStrategy unit = ValueFieldNamingStrategy.of(configurableEnvironment);
        final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .disableHtmlEscaping()
                .disableInnerClassSerialization()
                .setFieldNamingStrategy(unit)
                .create();
        try ( final JsonReader jsonReader = /*...open JSON reader here...*/ ) {
            final Test test = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, Test.class);
            Assertions.assertEquals("FName", test.name);
            Assertions.assertEquals("LName", test.data);
        }
    }

    private static final class Test {

        @Value("${name}")
        private String name;

        @Value("${data}")
        private String data;

    }

}
```